# WooCommerce.NET Get all products Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, woocommerce, blazor

I'm new with c# and i start learning with blazor. I'm trying to get all products from woocommerce api from my store. To check code is working i want to count products in a list but still no success. All the time list with products is empty. This is a full code from razor component:

```
@page "/woocommercepage"

@using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3;
@using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.Extension;


<p>Products count:@products.Count()</p>
<br />


@code 
{
    public static List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    public class woo
    {
       
        public static async Task<List<Product>> call()
        {

            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("https://mypage.com/wp-json/wc/v3/", "ck_000000", "cs_000000");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

            string SKU = "box";

            Dictionary<string, string> pDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            pDic.Add("sku", SKU);

            var products = await wc.Product.GetAll(pDic);

            return products;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `call`?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a class in your razor view that does not get called.
In the `@code` block there are several overrides available. In this case you will need the `OnInitializedAsync()` method. This method gets called when your razor view is being served. Make your call here and update your viewstate.

```
public static List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("https://mypage.com/wp-json/wc/v3/", "ck_000000", "cs_000000");
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

        string SKU = "box";

        Dictionary<string, string> pDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pDic.Add("sku", SKU);

        var products = await wc.Product.GetAll(pDic);

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but still list is empty. I tried call by postman to be sure string and keys are ok and working fine. On firefox console getting error: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.Product, WooCommerce.NET, Version=0.8.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ff41d0b6c937438d]]

Comment: Could you post your json result from the webcall. Also include the `Product` class so we can see why the response isn't being deserialized into the object.

Comment: I think this is the case. I have no result from json request. I checked in firefox console and nothing comes back. Function product: 'using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using WooCommerceNET.Base;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2;

namespace WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Product : JsonObject
    {
        public Product();

        public static string Endpoint { get; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? shipping_taxable { get; set; }
etc...

Comment: If you want to deserialize a json to an object they need to have public getters and setters. Endpoint is missing a setter so that might cause some issues.

Answer (score -1):

I have this code (in VB...sory). See if it helps...

```
        Public Function WC_LstProducts(Optional ByVal status As String = "any", Optional ByVal limit As Integer = 50) As List(Of Product)
            Dim res As New List(Of Product)
            Dim tmpRes As New List(Of Product)
            Dim page As Integer = 1
            Dim hasPages As Boolean = True
            Try
                Do While hasPages
                    tmpRes = WCAPI.Product.GetAll(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {
                                                        {"status", status},
                                                        {"per_page", limit},
                                                        {"page", page}
                                                    }).Result
                    If tmpRes.Count <= 0 Then
                        hasPages = False
                    Else
                        res.AddRange(tmpRes)
                        page += 1
                    End If
                Loop

            Catch ex As Exception                    
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "WC_LstProducts (ClassWoo): ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Err.Clear()
            Finally
                page = Nothing
                tmpRes = Nothing
            End Try
            Return res
        End Function
```

It should not be hard to convert to C# (it will be a good practice for you:))

Then you can use it like this:

```
Dim myList As List(Of Product)
myList = New List(Of Product)
myList = WC_LstProducts()
Dim counter As Integer
counter = myList.Count
```